# is there any way to show more than 1000 sublist lines in SuiteLet NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

i have created a suitelet with sublist showing the results of saved search (1000+ results).
Is there any way to show more than 1000 lines in sublists of suitelet as my search has more than 1000 lines?

Answer (score 0):

Without any of your code I cannot give you anything specific, but I can give you an example of how you would pull more than 1,000 lines/results from a saved search in SuiteScript.

The `.run()` method has a limit of 4,000 records I believe, so it could work, but I've been using the `.runPaged()` method to pull 10,000+ results from some of my saved searches.

```
let sObj = search.load({id: SEARCH_ID,type: SEARCH_TYPE}),
holdres = [];

let pd = sObj.runPaged({pageSize: 1000});
for(let i = 0; i < pd.pageRanges.length; i++) {
  let cp = pd.fetch(i);
  cp.data.forEach(r => {
    let ri = {};

    r.columns.forEach(col => {
      ri[col["name"]] = r.getValue({name: col["name"]});
    });

    holdres.push(ri);
  });
}

console.log(holdres);
```

This example pulls 1,000 records at a time, but will continue to pull results and loop through them (1,000 at a time). Then it just stores them in an array and uses the field names from NetSuite.